# How to remove spaces between a string in Docxtemplater?

Tags: javascript, docxtemplater

`{#form}{importantFacts}{/form}`

The problem is that the string takes over the whole line

For example :

`1.                                       This                           is                          test`

`2.      This      is      a       longer    string    so      spacing      is       generated       less`

However if i give longer strings it works fine , Basically the behaviour is that it covers the whole line.. how to remove these whitepspaces

Please let me know if more code needs to be shown.

**Generating doc file**

```
const tempFileName = `output-${new Date().getTime()}.docx`;
    const content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, formPath), 'binary');
    const zip = new PizZip(content);
    const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {nullGetter: () => " ", linebreaks: true});
    doc.setData(data);
    doc.render()
    const buf = doc.getZip().generate({type: 'nodebuffer'});
    fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, tempFileName), buf);
```

**Function used to print array of strings**

```
function formatArrayLines(lines: string[]) {
  let outputString = '';
  let i = 1;
  for (const line of lines) {
    outputString += `${i}. ${line}\n\n`
    i++;
  }
  return outputString;
}
```

Comment: `.trim()` ? I can't offer more. Not familiar with that template syntax.

Comment: no the orignal string is fine ... the template generates spacing for some reason.. thanks for helping tho

Comment: I see. Interesting. And is there a way to format a var? I have the github open and am looking

Comment: In the "interactive demo" there appears to be a "data" object returned on the loaded docx? Can you change the properties using javascript? Can you "trim" the white-spaces before rendering, that is? That is how I would do it if I knew how. .... Referring to this demo https://docxtemplater.com/demo/#simple

Comment: In a sense, could it be that the text justification is "justified". "Justified" will space words like that so it's like "newspaper print". Could this be a text/paragraph formatting issue? ... The *clue* for that is that more spacing, shrinks the spacing. (anyway upvoted you in hopes of more attention to this problem)

Comment: You might want to show more of your code to rule out / rule in the other possibilities.

Comment: @GetSet I apologize for the late response , Updated the question :)

Comment: Your "edit" only shows `formatArrayLines` once. So where is that being called? That was on question tho in comments.

Comment: @GetSet it is being called just before sending the data to generate doc file .. input to that function is a simple string array .. but that as we can see gets converted to many white spaces in the .docx file

Comment: I don't know @Phill is it being converted to "whitespaces"? Seems like adding *more* spaces don't result in less spaces. Sounds like a formatting issue on styles of docx. Just saying. But you know, you being selfish with the code and all, what do i know

Comment: I upvoted you tho. Text looks "justified". A styling issue. You can test it yourself. Open any wordprocessor or "publishing" app: type 3 relatively short words and set the paragraph to "justified". Text gets aligned so right edge is "neat" too. Thats what "justified" means.

Comment: @GetSet you were right setting text align to left fixed this thank you so much !!

Comment: Glad it worked out @Phil. If you can post your solution to your own question, I will upvote it. I am curious on how that code looks for the text align. But in any event, glad you got that part of the code resolved.

Comment: `{#form}{importantFacts}{/form}` i just selected this and selcted text align `left` it was previously set to `justified` which was the source of the problem :)

Comment: Ok, I get that part @Phil. But I meant post your source code so this question can help someone else later down the line. You *can* answer your own questions here, I think. And I can upvote. You can "accept". In this way, your solution will help future readers. No one really likes to dive in thru comments

Comment: @GetSet done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to this problem is not related to the source code but the alignment in the document

`{#form}{importantFacts}{/form}`

`So selecting this and setting text align left solved the problem.`